# GoodMan heat pump only heating a few minutes at 88 deg before I the air goes back to room temp and the elements turn on

Tags: heat-pump

I have a Goodman heat pump with a A30-10 air handler.
When the thermostat turns on the heat, it starts to warm the duct air to about 87-88 deg and then I hear a humming sound start and get louder, stops and starts the humming again, several times, at this point, the duct air starts to drop and go to room temp, 70 deg.  Then the heating elements turn on until the thermostat temp is reached.  This happens every time the system turns on.  I have a 2 story, one HP for each floor.  The other unit operates in the HP mode at 88-90 deg without turning on the heating elements.  I've swapped the thermostats, no change.  IT's only 30-40 F outside.  What could cause the loss of heat and for the elements to turn on?  The air Handler has a bower sequencer, heating sequencer and a 24vt transformer.  Is my problem with the air handler, or is it coming from the outside condenser, defrost board?  the outdoor unit continues to run during the whole cycle.  Thanks for any help in the right direction. I just had the R-22 topped off a week ago.

Comment: If it needed to be 'topped off' it had a leak. Did you find the leak as well? If you didn't, you're just throwing away expensive R-22.

Comment: If it worked OK after being topped off then failed a few days later I would highly suspect a refrigerant leak.